# Facebook Connect - Login bug - An error ocurred. Please try again later

Tags: facebook, authentication, dialog

The login box popup shown on clicking the "Facebook Connect" shows a "An error occurred. Please try again later" error for a certain flow(described below)

And looks like [we're not the only ones seeing this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1016164)

1. Login to facebook.com
2. Goto webapp and click on facebook connect button to login
3. Logout from webapp
4. Logout from facebook.com
5. try step 2 again

Is this common ? I tried [filing a bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create), but that's buggy as well(gets stuck)

When I view the access tokens under the "Access Token Debugger" tool, it says "The session is invalid because the user logged out." But if I goto facebook.com, I see that I'm logged in.

Comment: Is your app in Sandbox mode, and you logged in with a non-permitted account? That was the issue for me when I got this error.